# Python pandas select rows by list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, select, time-series

How to select multiple rows of a dataframe by list of dates

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))

In[1]: df

Out[1]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.084393 -2.460860 -0.118468  0.543618
2013-01-02 -0.024358 -1.012406 -0.222457  1.906462
2013-01-03 -0.305999 -0.858261  0.320587  0.302837
2013-01-04  0.527321  0.425767 -0.994142  0.556027
2013-01-05  0.411410 -1.810460 -1.172034 -1.142847
2013-01-06 -0.969854  0.469045 -0.042532  0.699582

myDates = ["2013-01-02", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-06"]
```

So the output should be

```
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-02 -0.024358 -1.012406 -0.222457  1.906462
2013-01-04  0.527321  0.425767 -0.994142  0.556027
2013-01-06 -0.969854  0.469045 -0.042532  0.699582
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `index.isin()` method to create a logical index for subsetting:

```
df[df.index.isin(myDates)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was too easy.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your entry into a DateTimeIndex:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(myDates)]

                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-02 -0.047710 -1.827593 -0.944548 -0.149460
2013-01-04  1.437924  0.126788  0.641870  0.198664
2013-01-06  0.408820 -1.842112 -0.287346  0.071397
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `timeseries` containing hours and minutes in the index (e.g. `2022-03-07 09:03:00+00:00` instead of `2022-03-07`), and you want to filter by dates (without hours, minutes, etc.), you can use the following:

```
df.loc[np.isin(df.index.date, myDates)]
```

If you try `df.loc[df.index.date.isin(myDates)]` it might not work and python will throw an error saying `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'`, and this is why we use `np.isin`.

This is an old post but I think this can be useful to a lot of people (such as myself).